# Analogue of Weierstrass Approsimation Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

The following theorems are well knows:

> **Weierstrass Approximation Theorem** Given a continuous function on $f\colon [a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, there exists a sequence of real polynomials, which converges uniformly to $f$ on $[0,1]$.
>
> For any measurable function $f\colon E\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $E$ a measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}$, there exists a sequence of simple functions which converge **pointwise** to $f$ on $E$.

**Question:** Is there an analogue of Weierstrass theorem for measurable functions, namely: *given any measurable function $f$ on a set $E$ of finite measure, there exists a sequence of simple functions which converge uniformly to $f$*.

Simple function means a finite linear combination of characteristic functions $\chi_{E_i}$'s where $E_i$ is measurable.

---

Question can be stated as follows also: in Weierstrass theorem, replace $[a,b]$ by a set of finite measure; replace $f$ by measurable function; and consider simple functions instead of polynomials; does the resultant statement true?

Comment: Egorov's theorem says its approximately true (on a finite measure space).

Comment: But Egorove's theorem doesn't guarantee "a.e.".

Comment: Well, you can't, as Jordan's answer shows.

Answer (score 1):

Consider any measurable function $f$ which is not bounded. Any function $g$ which is a finite linear combination of characteristic functions is clearly bounded, so $\Vert f-g \Vert_\infty=\infty$